Period of function $f(x) = \{x\} + \{x + \frac{1}{3}\} + \{x + \frac{2}{3}\}$
Consider the function $f(x) = \{x\} + \{x + \frac{1}{3}\} + \{x + \frac{2}{3}\}$
Let's break this into three individual functions $g(x) = \{x\}$, $h(x) = \{x + \frac{1}{3}\}$, and $i(x) =  \{x + \frac{2}{3}\}$. The period of $f(x)$ would be the LCM of these 3 periods.
Now, I know that when a quantity, say "$a$", is multiplied inside a function, its new period $T_{new} = \frac{T_{old}}{a}$, which does not depend upon whether something was added or subtracted inside the function.
Shouldn't the period of $f(x)$ be $1$, because the period of each $g(x), h(x)$ and $i(x)$ is also $1$? But the actual period is $\frac{1}{3}$.
Question: What would the be the period of $f(x)$?

What is the LCM for real numbers?

Why should the period of the sum be the lcm of the periods?

no,smallest Period should Not always be LCM of given three parts, Consider $h(x)=|\cos(\pi x)|$, $g(x)=|\sin(\pi x)|$, Each of them has period "1", But their addition has period $0.5$

Even more extreme example: Period of $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ is $\pi$, but their sum has arbitrarily small period.

@ultralegend5385,To be precise, Constant functions have no defined fundamental period

The fundamental period $T_{fundamental}$ of a periodic function $f(x)$ is defined as the least positive real value of $T$ for which
$$f(x+T)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
In the given problem, notice that $$g\bigg(x+\frac{1}{3}\bigg)= h(x), h\bigg(x+\frac{1}{3}\bigg)=i(x) \ \ and \ \ i\bigg(x+\frac{1}{3}\bigg)=g(x)\ \ \\\big[\because \{ x+a \}=\{x\}, \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}\big]$$
$$\implies f\bigg(x+\frac{1}{3}\bigg)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Therefore, the period of $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Thanks for the help! One more thing, why did you choose $\frac{1}{3}$ specifically? Is it because you "felt" it would fit (as an instinct) or is there some thinking behind it?

given that $f(x) = \{x\} + \{x + \frac{1}{3}\} + \{x + \frac{2}{3}\}$
It can be rewritten using property $\displaystyle \left\{y\right\}=y-\lfloor y\rfloor$
$f(x)=x+x+\frac{1}{3}+x+\frac{2}{3}-\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor x+\frac{1}{3}\rfloor-\lfloor x+\frac{2}{3}\rfloor$
$f(x)=3x+1-[\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{1}{3}\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{2}{3}\rfloor]$
Now using the property that $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{1}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{2}{n}\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac{3}{n}\rfloor....\lfloor x+\frac{n-1}{n}\rfloor=\lfloor nx\rfloor$
$f(x)=3x+1-\lfloor 3x\rfloor$
$f(x)=\{3x\}+1$
Now shortest period of $g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is $1$, Hence shortest period of $g(x)=\lfloor kx\rfloor$ is $\frac{1}{k}$ where $k$ is an integer
So period of $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$
